# Django save uploaded file

Tags: python, django, save

I want to upload a file, what I am able to do with the code stated below, but I also need to save all the uploads in different folder with different names. If 2 users upload the same file from browser, then in the folder it should be saved with different name or Unique Identification number.
Following is my code:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import openpyxl


def index(request):
    if "GET" == request.method:
        return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {})
    else:
        excel_file = request.FILES["excel_file"]

        # you may put validations here to check extension or file size

        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file)

        # getting all sheets
        sheets = wb.sheetnames
        print(sheets)

        # getting a particular sheet
        worksheet = wb["Sheet1"]
        print(worksheet)

        # getting active sheet
        active_sheet = wb.active
        print(active_sheet)

        # reading a cell
        print(worksheet["A1"].value)

        excel_data = list()
        # iterating over the rows and
        # getting value from each cell in row
        for row in worksheet.iter_rows():
            row_data = list()
            for cell in row:
                row_data.append(str(cell.value))
                print(cell.value)
            excel_data.append(row_data)

        return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {"excel_data":excel_data})
```

Answer (score 0):

Give you a Django FileField way Implemention:

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    suffix = filename[filename.rindex(".")+1:]
    return 'upfiles/{0}/{1}.{2}'.format(instance.user.username, get_randomfilename(),suffix)

class Picture(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
@parser_classes((MultiPartParser,))
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
def upload_picture(request):
    '''
    :input :{"file":f}
    :return:{"id":pictureId}
    '''
    if "file" in request.FILES:
        f = request.FILES["file"]
        picture = Picture()
        picture.user= request.user
        picture.file = f
        picture.save()
        return Response(data={"id":picture.id})
    else:
        return Response({},status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: @Hyaden This file should be in views.py  or models.py?

Comment: No,You can access it in any place where you can access model object。In fact you can access it in batch script including django env setup。File is stored in harddisk or other media store backend

Comment: Actually I am very new to Django and all , can you help me with simpler solution

Comment: Which country are you in?

Comment: Can you help me out?

Comment: @CyleySimon That's the simplest solution and the one proposed in the official documentation. You pass a function as an argument for `upload_to`.